# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: oracle, pls-00103

What is the problem with this package as it is giving an error?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_SHOW_CUST_DETAILS 
AS
    PROCEDURE SHOW_CUST_DETAILS( myArg VARCHAR2);
END PKG_SHOW_CUST_DETAILS;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_SHOW_CUST_DETAILS 
AS
    PROCEDURE SHOW_CUST_DETAILS(myArg VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myArg);        
    END SHOW_CUST_DETAILS;

END PKG_SHOW_CUST_DETAILS;
/
```

On compilation of the above script, I am getting the following errors:

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE PKG_SHOW_CUST_DETAILS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

The package is very simple and I am not able to compile it. I searched earlier answers on this error message and none of them did solve my problem.
I am consistently getting this error for 2 more packages and I am stuck on this error message no matter what I do. I even tried to strip everything to the barest minimum as shown above, but the error message does not seem to go away.
BTW I am executing this on command line SQL plus session after logging into my Oracle 11G database.
YES- SET SERVEROUTPUT ON  -- is executed and the error message has nothing to do with this command.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing a `/` after the  `create` for the package definition.

Comment: Yes after adding a '/' on  a new line as the first character after the definition solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: And BTW, the code is to be executed as a script and only then will it be successful.

Answer (score 74):

At line 5 there is a `/` missing.

There is a good answer on the differences between `;` and `/` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash).

Basically, when running a `CREATE` block via script, you need to use `/` to let SQLPlus know when the block ends, since a PL/SQL block can contain many instances of `;`.

#### [Further reference](https://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/191167/)

SQL*Plus treats PL/SQL subprograms in the same manner as SQL commands, except that a semicolon ( ; ) or a blank line does not terminate and execute a block. Terminate PL/SQL subprograms by entering a period (.) by itself on a new line. You can also terminate and execute a PL/SQL subprogram by entering a slash (/) by itself on a new line.

. . .

SQL*Plus stores the subprograms you enter in the SQL buffer. Execute the current subprogram with a RUN or slash (/) command. A semicolon ( ; ) is treated as part of the PL/SQL subprogram and will not execute the command.

Comment: People coming here because of `PLS-00103` after creating a package with **Liquibase**: if you are using `<sql>` to do it, you have to put the package definition in one `<sql>` block, and the actual package body in another `<sql>` block after that.

Answer (score 2):

For me / had to be in a new line.

For example

`create type emp_t;/`

didn't work

but

`create type emp_t;`

`/`

worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE TABLE ...')` works, for example:

```
DECLARE 
   myVar INT;
BEGIN
SELECT 2 INTO myVar FROM dual;
IF myVar > 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('Create Global Temporary Table TestTemp ( id VARCHAR2(2) ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS');
END IF;
END;
```

Reference to [Create Table As within PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587022/create-table-as-within-pl-sql)

Answer (score -3):

Run package declaration and body separately.

Comment: Explaining a little bit more would be appreciated by the OP, I think.

Comment: This would work around the issue, without really explaining the problem with the original code sample. Some teams will separate spec and body into separate files as a matter of course.