# Use anonymous block in Entity Framwork DbMigration.Sql function

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use EF6.0 + Oracle 10g and code first approach.

In my migration there is such fragment of code:

```
Sql(@"
begin
    insert into t_new1 (p1, p2) 
       select p1, p2 from t_old1;

    insert into t_new2 (p1, p2) 
       select p1, p2 from t_old2;
...other DML operations.....
end;");
```

When I try to apply my migration using `Update-Database`, I get error which does not give any hints about true nature of a problem.

It looks like

> Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
>
> begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with   
>   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe

I suspect that it's not allowed to use `Begin-End` blocks in `DbMigration Sql` function. But I can not state it for sure and would like to hear some advices about this situation.

As a workaround it's possible to create stored procedure, execute it and then drop. However it seems not enough elegant.

Comment: can you run the commands somewhere else without errors? Can you isolate the command that is causing the exception? "other DML operations" is not very specific.

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334067/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-create)? i.e. is it the `;` character that should be a `/`?

Comment: I used `Update-Database -script` to generate plain Sql script.
After that this script was run directly with SqlPlus. Everything works as supposed without errors and warnigs.

Comment: @Default
Unfortunately, adding `/` in new line after `end;` had now effect.