# Oracle package error. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
    create  or replace package pachet_f_p is
    function majorare_sal_manageri(sal in  NUMBER, majorare in  NUMBER) return NUMBER;
    end pachet_f_p;


    create or replace package body pachet_f_p
    is
     create or replace function majorare_sal_manageri(sal in  NUMBER, majorare in  NUMBER)
    return INTEGER is
    nr_angajati INTEGER :=0;
    begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Angajatii care primesc majorare de '|| majorare || 'au ID-urile urmatoare :');
    /*
    declare
    cursor numara_ang_cccc is
      select ID from MANAGERI where SALARIU = sal;
      m_ID MANAGERI.ID%TYPE;
    begin
      open numara_ang_c;
      loop
        fetch numara_ang_c into m_ID;
        exit when numara_angajati_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(m_ID);
        update MANAGERI 
        set
        SALARIU = SALARIU + majorare
        where  ID = m_ID;
        nr_angajati := nr_angajati +1;
      end loop;
      close numara_ang_cccc;
    end; 
    */
    return nr_angajati;
    end majorare_sal_manageri;

    end pachet_f_p;
```

I can run the first 3 rows, but the rest of it gets an error: 
Error(5,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure subtype type         current cursor delete exists prior
Can someone, please, find what I did  wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334067/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-create#20334358 that can help you with a resolution.

Comment: PLSQL..........I'm just dumb and tired. Thanks

Comment: PLSQL...................................................I saw that question, but doesn't work for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Are you using oracle or mariadb?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: Also I'm using Oracle Database 12c

Comment: Error(2,14): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'MAJORARE_SAL_MANAGERI' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

Comment: Now I have this error. MAJORARE_SAL_MANAGERI being the name of the function

Comment: The method must remain the same between body and spec, change function majorare_sal_manageri  to return the same type, both number or integer.

Comment: I changed both to NUMBER but the first error came up

Comment: Error(3,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure subtype type    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current cursor delete exists prior The symbol "CREATE" was ignored.

Comment: and with INTEGER is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create package specifications and Package body next(two separate pl/sql blocks)this compiles with no errors in Sql Developer

```
       create  or replace package pachet_f_p is
          function majorare_sal_manageri(sal in  NUMBER, majorare in  NUMBER) 
            return NUMBER;
        end pachet_f_p;
       -- add back slash here
       /    
        create or replace package body pachet_f_p
        is
         --create or replace (comment or remove this)
         function majorare_sal_manageri(sal in  NUMBER, majorare in  NUMBER)
        return number is
        nr_angajati number :=0;
        begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Angajatii care primesc majorare de '|| majorare || 'au ID-urile urmatoare :');
        /*
        declare
        cursor numara_ang_cccc is
          select ID from MANAGERI where SALARIU = sal;
          m_ID MANAGERI.ID%TYPE;
        begin
          open numara_ang_c;
          loop
            fetch numara_ang_c into m_ID;
            exit when numara_angajati_cursor%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line(m_ID);
            update MANAGERI 
            set
            SALARIU = SALARIU + majorare
            where  ID = m_ID;
            nr_angajati := nr_angajati +1;
          end loop;
          close numara_ang_cccc;
        end; 
        */
          return nr_angajati;
          end majorare_sal_manageri;
         end pachet_f_p;
/
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so so so much!!! I really appreciate it!